# Inner model with a $\mathit{\Delta}^1_3$-good well-ordering of the reals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, constructibility

The constructible universe $L$ has some nice properties:

1. $L$ has a $\mathit{\Delta}^1_2$-good well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. (Gödel, Addison)
2. For any $\mathit{\Sigma}^1_2$ formula $\varphi(x)$ and a real $r \in \mathbb{R}\cap L, \ \varphi(r) \iff \varphi(r)^L$. (Shoenfield)
3. For any $\mathit{\Sigma}^1_2$ set $A$, either $A\subseteq L$ or $A$ contains a perfect set. (Mansfield, Solovay)

My questions are:

- Is there, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, an inner model that satisfies all three statements above with $\mathit{\Delta}^1_2$ and $\mathit{\Sigma}^1_2$ replaced by $\mathit{\Delta}^1_3$ and $\mathit{\Sigma}^1_3$, respectively?
- What about $\mathit{\Delta}^1_n$ and $\mathit{\Sigma}^1_n$ with $n > 3$?
- What if instead we work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + large cardinals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The situation is a bit more complicated than you might hope because of the periodicity phenomena in the projective hierarchy. For odd $n$, assuming $\mathbf{\Delta}^1_{n-1}$-determinacy, the set $Q_n$ of reals that are $\Delta^1_n$ in a countable ordinal is $\Pi_n^1$ definable, so its complement is a $\Sigma_n^1$ set that has no element in any inner model with a good $\Delta^1_n$ wellorder. So no such model is $\Sigma_n^1$-correct.

The set $Q_n$ is the set of reals in $M_{n-2}$, the minimum inner model with $n-2$ Woodin cardinals, which does have a good $\Delta^1_n$-wellorder of the reals. The union of all countable $\Sigma^1_n$ sets is going to be the set of all $\Delta^1_n$ reals by the effective perfect set theorem, so $M_{n-2}$ will satisfy the version of the perfect set theorem you want. But really this is not quite the right theorem, I think, since $Q_n$ is $\Pi^1_n$ not $\Sigma^1_n$. On the other hand, there is a largest countable $\Pi^1_n$ set (analogous to the largest countable $\Pi^1_1$ set, the mastercodes of $L$), but this is actually strictly larger than $Q_n$.

On the other hand, if there is no inner model with a Woodin cardinal and every set has a sharp, then the core model $K$ is $\Sigma^1_3$-correct and has a $\Delta^1_3$-good wellorder. Well, I'm not sure if this has been proved in such generality, the version I know assumes there is a measurable cardinal. Maybe an expert can fill this in.

For the even levels, under large cardinal assumptions, the situation should be very similar to the one for $L$, so probably exactly what you want is true. I think this cannot be done without some large cardinal assumptions, or really determinacy/mouse existence assumptions. I'm getting a little tired of writing for now, hopefully I'll update later.

Some references: Steel's "Projectively wellordered inner models," Steel's "Ordinal definability in models of determinacy," Steel's *Core Model Iterability Problem* (for the correctness of $K$), Kechris-Martin-Solovay's "Introduction to Q-theory."

Comment: Do you mean for exactly one of your $\Delta$'s to be `\mathbf`'d?

Comment: Approximately. Can't promise perfection, but there is a good reason.

Comment: @LSpice They mean different things. For instance, every singleton is trivially ${\bf\Pi^1_1}$ (= coanalytic) but there is a largest countable $\Pi^1_1$ (= "lightface" coanalytic, basically the complement of the *computable* continuous image of a Polish space) set.

Comment: Re [1](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1154989) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1155066), I didn't mean to suggest that they didn't mean different things, only to check that just one occurrence `\mathbf`d wasn't a typo.  (I particularly mentioned because the original post `\mathit`d $\Delta$'s, and this post didn't, and I didn't know if *that* was significant.)  Probably obviously, this is not my area, and I was just trying to proofread.  I am happy to delete my comment (now comments).